# JavaScript trouble detecting mouse wheel event

Tags: javascript, events, mouse, mousewheel

I'm trying to capture the mouse event. Here is the code I'm trying:

```
if(window.addEventListener) { document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', zoom_handler, false); } 
else { document.onmousewheel = zoom_handler; }

alert("test"); //I see this alert so I assume the code above it is run
```

//...

```
function zoom_handler(event) {

    var delta = 0;

    if (!event) event = window.event;
    // normalize the delta
    if (event.wheelDelta) {
        // IE and Opera
        delta = event.wheelDelta / 60;
    } else if (event.detail) {
        // W3C
        delta = -event.detail / 2;
    }

    alert("Delta: " + delta);


}
```

Except the problem is I see nothing when I try wheeling up and down on my page, so I guess I'm not capturing the event properly. For reference, I've been trying to follow this tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/08/javascript-mouse-scroll-event-down-example.html

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that the way you implemented it, is going to work only in some browsers, not in Chrome for example. Did you try to put the

```
document.onmousewheel = zoom_handler;
```

outside the else statement?
Doing so, makes it work on my Chrome Browser running on OSX Lion (Mac).

This is how I tested on my computer:

```
if(window.addEventListener) { document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', zoom_handler, false); } 
document.onmousewheel = zoom_handler;

alert("test"); //I see this alert so I assume the code above it is run
```

Hope that fixes it.

Comment: Hey that's awesome thanks a lot! When I saw the IF I just instinctively put an else clause on the other condition, which was wrong of me.